# foley prop needed: a stack of cash

Tags: foley, props, money

need a prop for the handling of cash about yeah big:

[image]

Since, you know, I don't have a stack of cash that size on me.  on screen this cash is pulled out of a counting machine, patted flat and placed on a table.

I'm cutting up an old book now, but any other thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The cut book ended up working out perfectly.  I needed a lot of bills (several hundred), and I needed the paper to sound both thick, non-laminated, and a little worn, so the book pages gave me the depth and almost the texture I needed.

To finish the trick I took a few real bills and put them on either side of the stack, and took about 15 book made bills, crumpled them, opened them back up and put them inside the rest of the stack in intervals.

foley went very quickly, and with a little eq they sounded exactly like they looked.

and now I have a new prop built.  :)

thx for the help.

Comment: Cheers for sharing! Will be useful in future!

Answer (score 1):

I keep hearing a beat up deck of cards being handled loosely, but maybe with the pitch down a couple of cents.

Or you could get $50 in singles from the bank.

Answer (score 1):

Use coins instead

Answer (score 0):

Possibly take a bunch of folded newspapers so they aren't too thin?

This might make that "flap" noise. Does someone flip it like a deck of cards or do they just move it?

A bunch of b&w newspapers folded to be the same size of a wad of cash (like USA Today) could work..

I'll think of more and ask my colleagues and I'll let you know what we come up with.

Answer (score 0):

monopoly money? already cut the right size. to be honest i cant see real money and paper sounding noticeably different, its the sync performance that really matters to make you believe the sound.